# Python 3.x selenium errors

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying for a web crawler with selenium and I'm getting the following errors.I'm new to python.Please help me with these errors:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/python/Python3.5/selenium_program.py", line 6, in 
>       driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
>
> File
>   "C:\python\Python3.5\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py",
>   line 103, in **init**
>       self.binary, timeout)
>
> File
>   "C:\python\Python3.5\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\extension_connection.py",
>   line 51, in **init**
>       self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile, timeout=timeout)
>
> File
>   "C:\python\Python3.5\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py",
>   line 67, in launch_browser
>   self._start_from_profile_path(self.profile.path)
>
> File
>   "C:\python\Python3.5\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py",
>   line 90, in _start_from_profile_path
>       env=self._firefox_env)
>
> File "C:\python\Python3.5\lib\subprocess.py", line 950, in **init**
>       restore_signals, start_new_session)
>
> File "C:\python\Python3.5\lib\subprocess.py", line 1220, in
>   _execute_child
>       startupinfo)
>
> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file
>   specified

my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

binary = FirefoxBinary("C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)

driver.implicitly_wait(30)

driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("http://www.google.com")
```

Comment: is this a question?

Comment: Please format your code and ask a clear question.

Comment: Yeah. It's now edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to escape the backslash  `\` with `\\` or `r''` or using slash `/`

```
binary = FirefoxBinary(r"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe")
```